# Android Build Failed: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I am getting two warnings:

```
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 28.0.3 not accepted.
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 28 not accepted.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

Deleted entire sdk folder in C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
And then redownloaded the sdk from android studio